# how to create player using ffmpeg on android?

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-mediaplayer

I have complied ffmpeg library for android 
could any guide me how to use it for showing the video on the screen.

Comment: I know we have to use [SDL](www.libsdl.org) over here.

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know ffmpeg is used for video conversion...
for showing a video use videoview or mediaplayer.

Comment: [FFmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) is a complete, cross-platform solution to record, convert and stream audio and video